# Website Performance Issues?

Tags: asp.net, performance

So my friend consulted me about a website he is trying to develop. The website would have over 120 web forms and I am thinking, thats a lot of web forms. Any performance issues we need to worry about? because I have not developed a site with that many pages before. your comments would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have less maintenance issues in a project of quite a big size like the one you mention I would suggest you to use ASP.NET MVC. 
This will also make your html code inherently cleaner as you have further control over it, and at the same time it will be less likely that you will have any performance issues.
Also, as I learnt from personal experience, the compilation time of the ASP.NET with web forms decreases a lot with size and this could cause further slow down in development.

Answer (score 1):

Performance issues, no. Code maintenance issues, maybe.

If the web forms are similar in layout and vary only by content then I would recommend using a CMS to store the content if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just do your basic optimization. Css/Sprits (minimize http connections), good efficient code, you also need to be more specific on your questions to stackoverflow in the future.

Run ySlow http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

Answer (score 0):

When you are loading a page from a website, it really doesn't matter if you have a million pages. The problem would be if that site was receiving 1000 page views per second.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to worry too much about the number of forms in the application, you only need to worry about the performance of any code that's running when you request any of those pages.

From a maintenance perspective maybe look at whether duplication could be reduced by making good use of user controls, master pages, push business logic in to a dedicated lib rather than scattering it around all the code behind files etc.

As it's a new project it's worth looking at ASP.Net MVC as an alternative to the Web Forms approach.  I personally prefer the MVC route but Web Forms has improved as well.